# data structure for counting frequencies in a database table-like format

Tags: java, data-structures, data-mining

i was wondering if there is a data structure optimized to count frequencies against data that is stored in a database table-like format. for example, the data comes in a (comma) delimited format below.

```
col1, col2, col3
x, a, green
x, b, blue
...
y, c, green
```

now i simply want to count the frequency of col1=x or col1=x and col2=green. i have been storing the data in a database table, but in my profiling and from empirical observation, database connection is the bottle-neck. i have tried using in-memory database solutions too, and that works quite well; the only problem is memory requirements and quirky init/destroy calls.

also, i work mainly with java, but have experience with .net, and was wondering if there was any api to work with "tabular" data in a linq way using java.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you using the database? With the right queries the database ought to work well for what you're doing...

Comment: i simply create a database table. i know there are ways to optimize queries (i.e. using indexes), but they differ from database to database. also, there is no way to know which indexes to create (on which columns or combination of columns) because at runtime, the algorithms determine which columns are correlated. also, the program accepts as input any tabular dataset, so i create the database tables at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

How about a nested TreeMap?  For example, say you have the following records:

```
col1=v, col2=v2
col1=v, col2=v3
```

You want to be able to query the structure and ask, "how many times did col1 have the value v?"

I'd use the following code to insert values into the structure:

```
TreeMap tm = new TreeMap();
//the map hasn't seen this column name yet
if(!tm.containsKey(columnName)){
    //mark the column value as being seen once
    tm.put(columnName, (new TreeMap()).put(colVal, 1));
}else{
    //the map has seen the column name.
    TreeMap valueMap = tm.get(columnName);
    if(valueMap.containsKey(colVal)){
        //we've seen this column value before.
        //Increment the number of times we've seen it
        int valCount = valueMap.get(colVal);
        valueMp.put(colVal, valCount++);
    }else{
        //we've have not seen this column value before.
        valueMap.put(colVal, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: i've tried maps of maps to tackle this problem before. it is very slow and can require prohibitive memory requirements. for example, if every column had two values, and we had 10 columns, the combinations are 2^10.

Comment: In this implementation, there would not be 2^10 entries though.  In this code, there will be 10 entries in the top level tree (1 entry for each unique column name). Each node of the top level tree will contain a single TreeMap which contains two entries (one for each value).  In this case, we would have 20 total entries (each of the 10 columns has two values).

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Multiset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) data structure that keeps track of the frequencies for you. Here is the sample code using that data structure (from [google-guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html)).

```
void frequencyCounter()
{
    Multiset<String> counter = HashMultiset.create();

    counter.add("col1" + "=" + "x");
    counter.add("col2" + "=" + "x");
    counter.add("col2" + "=" + "x");

    System.out.println("how many times did col2 have the value x?");
    System.out.println(counter.count("col2" + "=" + "x"));
}
```

Points to be noted.

- i am concatenating the column name
  (col1) and its value (x) with (=) as
  the delimiter while adding to the
  Multiset
- I am repeating the same    process to
  check for the frequency a
  particular value in a given column

Comment: if i used the multiset object/class, i don't think it would work. because each add would add a string like this ("col1=x,col2=y,col3=green"). and then i'd need for count to be able to compute a filter like these 1) col1=x, 2) col1=y and col2=x, or 3) col3=green,col2=x. note that there is column orders are not important, and how i create the filters may put col3 before col1 or col2.

Comment: @user373312 so you are saying that you want to use ("col1=x,col2=y,col3=green") as the key?